# Any way to get Netbeans to weave classes on Compile and Save in a Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, aspectj

I am using NetBeans in a Maven project. Recently we changed the
implementation of the aspects from Spring AOP to AspectJ compiler(With
AspectJ-maven-plugin plugin).

With the Clean and Build task the AspectJ plugin weaves all classes but
when saving a class with the feature "Compile On Save" activated the
aspects are not applied.

What Maven goal is triggered in Compile On Save process?
Could the aspects be applied automatically in the Compile On Save process?

I am running NetBeans 8.2 on Windows 10 x64.

Relevant part of the pom.xml

```
<project>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <XnoInline>true</XnoInline>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I cannot help you with Netbeans, but if you want "compile on save" to work for imported AspectJ Maven projects, you can use Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA, both with proper AspectJ add-ons installed and activated.

Answer (score 0):

no, weaving will never work with Compile on Save. The actual compilation on editor save is done by the netbeans internal parser/compiler and not by a maven goal. Netbeans just places the new generated class file in the right location but basically the resulting class file equals what to what vanilla jdk javac would compile.